# How to give data to a python thread that is running a client function?

Tags: python, multithreading

I'm currently working on a school project. I have a log in page which is using tkinter and I have a thread that is running a client function. I can get the data that the user inputs into tkinter however I'm struggling to find a way to give data to the client function to send to a pc that's running a server file which has a database stored on it. This is my current client file.

```
import threading 
import socket 
HOST = socket.gethostbyname(socket.gethostname())
PORT = 9997
ADDR = (HOST, PORT)
SIZE = 1024
FORMAT = "utf-8"
DISCONNECT_MSG = "!DISCONNECT"
class main():
    def __init__(self) -> None:
        pass 

    def Main(cls):
        cls.client = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
        cls.client.connect(ADDR)
        print(f"[CONNECTED] Client connected to server {HOST}:{PORT}")
        cls.funAndCoolFunction("awa")


    def funAndCoolFunction(cls, message):
            Connected = True
            serverSocket = cls.client
            msg = input("> ")

            serverSocket.send(msg.encode(FORMAT))

            if msg == DISCONNECT_MSG:
                Connected = False
            else:
                msg = serverSocket.recv(SIZE).decode(FORMAT)
                print(f"[SERVER] {msg}")
            
            return Connected

if __name__ == "__main__": main()
```

In the other file I'm running the thread as `clientConn = Client.main() clientThread = threading.Thread(target=clientConn.Main) clientThread.start()`

The function works as normal and displays the `[CONNECTED] Client connected to server {HOST}:{PORT}`

Comment: print(f"[SERVER] {msg}")
    serverSocket.sendall(...

Comment: Write a better to clean up.      clientConn = main()
        if __name__ == "__main__":     
            clientThread = threading.Thread(None, clientConn.Main)
            clientThread.start()